# C code encrypted file cannot be decrypted using openssl

Tags: c, openssl, rsa, libcrypto, libssl

This is the code that encrypts the file `test.txt` to `test.enc`.
Key pair `key.pem` and `key.pub` was generated using `openssl`:

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem
openssl rsa -in key.pem -out key.pub -pubout
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <limits.h>
#include <dirent.h>

#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

static int evp_aes_encrypt(char *in_path, char *out_path, EVP_PKEY *pkey)
{
    FILE *in_file = fopen(in_path, "rb");
    if (!in_file)
        return -1;

    FILE *out_file = fopen(out_path, "wb");
    if (!out_file)
    {
        fclose(in_file);
        return -1;
    }

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    if (!ctx)
    {
        fclose(in_file);
        fclose(out_file);
        return -1;
    }

    int len;
    unsigned char iv[EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];
    int i;
    unsigned char* ek = NULL;

    if (EVP_SealInit(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), &ek, &len, iv, &pkey, 1) != 1)
    {
        printf("1\n");
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
        fclose(in_file);
        fclose(out_file);
        return -1;
    }

    unsigned char in_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    unsigned char out_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE + EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];

    int bytes_read, bytes_written;
    while ((bytes_read = fread(in_buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, in_file)) > 0)
    {
        if (EVP_SealUpdate(ctx, out_buffer, &bytes_written, in_buffer, bytes_read) != 1) {
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
            fclose(in_file);
            fclose(out_file);
            return -1;
        }
        fwrite(out_buffer, 1, bytes_written, out_file);
    }

    if (EVP_SealFinal(ctx, out_buffer, &bytes_written) != 1) {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
        fclose(in_file);
        fclose(out_file);
        return -1;
    }

    fwrite(out_buffer, 1, bytes_written, out_file);

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    fclose(in_file);
    fclose(out_file);

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *pub = fopen("key.pub", "rb");
    EVP_PKEY *pkey = PEM_read_PUBKEY(pub, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    evp_aes_encrypt("test.txt", "test.enc", pkey);
    return 0;
}
```

Encrypted file then is being decrypted using `openssl` command:

```
openssl rsautl -in test.enc -out test.dec -inkey key.pem -decrypt
```

Then this error appears:

```
RSA operation error
407D290301000000:error:0200009F:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:pkcs decoding error:crypto/rsa/rsa_pk1.c:269:
407D290301000000:error:02000072:rsa routines:rsa_ossl_private_decrypt:padding check failed:crypto/rsa/rsa_ossl.c:499:
```

Seems like there is a problem with padding, but I have no idea how to fix it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you check the returned value of `evp_aes_encrypt`?

Comment: I am not sure that this can help solve this issue, cause it always returns 0 in my tests. I removed them here anyways. I think the problem is in how the encryption process is happening. P.S. Yes, I checked it, it always returns 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Seems like there is a problem with padding," -- actually the problem is you did only half the job.

`EVP_Seal/Open` does **hybrid encryption**, also called envelope (or enveloped) encryption. This is [described almost correctly in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) but I will rephrase to match the OpenSSL implementation and my preferences.

Encryption consists of three steps and *two different* encryptions:

0. generate a nonce key for the symmetric algorithm (called DEK)
1. encrypt DEK using RSA with recipient's public key (which you must already have, so this might be considered step -1, but it doesn't need to be repeated for each message)
2. encrypt the data using a symmetric cipher (in your example AES-256-CBC) using DEK and depending on the mode sometimes random IV/nonce (CBC uses an IV); also depending on the mode this may additionally produce an authentication tag (CBC does not)

Encryption steps 1 and 2 can be done in either order, but I believe this order is more common and it is definitely the one used in OpenSSL (`SealInit` does 0 and 1, `SealUpdate` and `SealFinal` together do 2).

**To decrypt you need all 2-4 data items** produced by steps 1 and 2: RSA-encrypted-DEK, IV if applicable, encrypted data, and tag if applicable. In real systems there are data structures that package up these data items, plus additional metadata: wikipedia mentions PKCS7 (nowadays replaced by CMS, and its variant SMIME) and PGP; there are also JOSE/JWE, XMLenc, and more. Decryption similarly requires *two steps*:

1. decrypt transmitted encrypted-DEK using RSA and locally-known private key
2. decrypt transmitted encrypted-data using same symmetric algorithm, decrypted DEK, if applicable transmitted IV/nonce, and if applicable transmitted tag

(and this time you must do them in this order).

However, to decrypt *with OpenSSL commandline* you need these items in separate files (except the tag for an authenticating mode, which commandline `enc` can't handle at all). Thus I modified your program to write encrypted-DEK, IV, and ciphertext to 3 files, as well as refactoring slightly to reduce the clutter, changing filenames to avoid conflict, and adding minimal error handling:

```
// SO76696165
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

static int evp_aes_encrypt(FILE *fin, FILE *fek, FILE *fiv, FILE *fenc, EVP_PKEY *pkey)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    if (!ctx) return -1;

    unsigned char iv[EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];
    unsigned char* ek = malloc(EVP_PKEY_get_size(pkey));
    int ekl, ivl;

    if (EVP_SealInit(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), &ek, &ekl, iv, &pkey, 1) != 1)
    { EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx); free(ek); return -2; }
    ivl = 16; // or EVP_CIPHER_CTX_get_iv_length(EVP_aes_256_cbc());
    fwrite (ek,ekl,1,fek); fwrite (iv,ivl,1,fiv);

    unsigned char in_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    unsigned char out_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE + EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];
    // actually this only needs + cipher_blocksize, but bytes are cheap now

    int bytes_read, bytes_written;
    while ((bytes_read = fread(in_buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, fin)) > 0)
    {
        if (EVP_SealUpdate(ctx, out_buffer, &bytes_written, in_buffer, bytes_read) != 1) {
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx); free(ek); return -3; }
        fwrite(out_buffer, 1, bytes_written, fenc);
    }

    if (EVP_SealFinal(ctx, out_buffer, &bytes_written) != 1) {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx); free(ek); return -4; }

    fwrite(out_buffer, 1, bytes_written, fenc);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx); free(ek); 
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *pub = fopen("76696165.pub", "rb");
    EVP_PKEY *pkey = PEM_read_PUBKEY(pub, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    FILE *fin = fopen("76696165.in", "rb");
    FILE *fek = fopen("76696165.ek", "wb");
    FILE *fiv = fopen("76696165.iv", "wb");
    FILE *fenc = fopen("76696165.enc", "wb");
    int err = evp_aes_encrypt(fin, fek, fiv, fenc, pkey);
    if( err ){ printf ("error in step %d\n", err);
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout); return 1; }
    // fclose not needed when exiting normally
    return 0;
}
```

After running this I have:

```
$ ls -rt1 76696165*
76696165.pub
76696165.prv
76696165.c
76696165.exe
76696165.in
76696165.iv
76696165.enc
76696165.ek
$ # STEP 1
$ openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey 76696165.prv <76696165.ek >76696165.dek
$ xxd 76696165.dek; xxd 76696165.iv
0000000: a46e 5084 e28b 8f9c 7fe3 a465 fbeb 4ed7  .nP........e..N.
0000010: 7c4b 38f5 3174 f905 3034 52df d992 da3d  |K8.1t..04R....=
0000000: 959b a611 3fbb 5486 b6c6 2056 f9ee 6f03  ....?.T... V..o.
$ # STEP 2
$ keyhex=$(xxd -p -c32 <76696165.dek) ivhex=$(xxd -p <76696165.iv) 
$ openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -K $keyhex -iv $ivhex <76696165.enc
Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary,
Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore—
While I nodded, nearly napping, suddenly there came a tapping,
As of some one gently rapping, rapping at my chamber door.
"'Tis some visiter," I muttered, "tapping at my chamber door—
            Only this and nothing more."
-- Edgar Allan Poe
```